# Force Barcode Scanner to scan in a particular field on Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have a form developed in Microsoft Access where users can scan barcodes and it does a lookup and updates a subform below.  All works fantastic, as long as the user stays in the barcode input field.  They have at times, left the field to scroll in the subform below.  If they do not click back into the "scan field" the scan is lost without any indication to them.

What I would like to do is one of 2 things:

1)  After they scroll in the subform, fire the mouseup event to take them back to the scan field in the main form.  I have been successful doing this when they click outside of the subform, but as soon as they do anything inside the subform (including scrolling), I cannot get the focus to go back to the scan field.

2)  If a barcode is scanned and they are not in the scan field, trigger an error message.  I'm completely at a loss for how to do this, since they could literally be anywhere on the form outside of the scan field, so this may not be possible.  My preference would be #1 above to handle the situation.

As mentioned above, I have tried the mouseup event and it works inside the main form.  I cannot seem to get it to work in the subform.

The below works when the user clicks anywhere in the main form

```vb
Private Sub Detail_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    txtItemBarcode.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Expected Result:  Set the focus back to txtItemBarcode, when user releases the mouse to scroll inside the subform.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have in mind, that picking a barcode is not different from entering some characters on the keyboard. No code can distinguish between these two happenings. So, educate the users.

Comment: I agree and this point has been very much communicated.  However, if I could programmatically take care of this particular event, it would take the "human" out of the equation for errors (at least, this specific one).